# Digitizing Tools error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I receive this message: *Digitizing Tools: Amend Line is disabled because layer CRS and project CRS do not match*.

If I set the CRS of the layer the same as the project CRS (W84 Pseudo Mercator) is misaligned and in a unknown location.

My project is EPSG: 3857 / WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator

First layer is a Bing Aerial (Web > OpenLayersPlugin > BingMaps > Bing Aerial) - CRS: EPSG 3857 / WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator

Another layers with shapefiles lines and points captured from OSM. - CRS: ESPG 4326 / WGS84, which is OK on top the base layer.

**About the error:** the layer in question is a shapefile line layer (roads) - CRS: ESPG 4326 / WGS84, which is OK on top the base layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change you project CRS to match that of the layer you are editing, and **not** the Layer's CRS from it's properties menu, as that is simply incorrect.

Comment: When I set the project CRS to macth (right button > Set Preject CRS from layer)  the layer is slightly misaligned.

Comment: what is your editing layer's CRS? what layers are you using as reference on your base map?

Comment: Pls see in the question above my project...

Answer (score 3):

The Digitizing tool does not work correctly with on-the-fly reprojection.

If you need the **project** CRS to be EPSG:3857, reproject the shapefiles layers using `Save As ...` to another filename and EPSG:3857, and remove the original layers from the project. Then you can use the digitizing tool without error messages.

Once finished with digitzing, you can save back to EPSG:4326.

**DON'T** **USE** `Set Layer CRS` to reproject, it will corrupt your data.

Answer (score 0):

In a new project the tool works fine. It has no Bing layers.The CRS is the same for all layers and project.

Comment: If you use the QuickmapServices plugin, you can still have Bing layers, and project CRS set to EPSG:4326.

Comment: But by the experience  I made it seems that we can not use Pseudo Mercator. It's the only difference I see, **or** perhaps what @HDunn mentioned above.

Comment: With QMS, you can add Bing layers in **layer** CRS EPSG:3857 to your new project without the need to change the **project** CRS to it too.